# How do I get the first child of each of these rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 rows, each with 2 text inputs. How do I go through each row w/ class "myRow" and, within each row, get the first child that has class "This"? I can get the first "This" class of row 1 but can't seem to get row 2.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkPZm/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#btn').click(function(){
    $(".myRow").each(function(){
        var r = $(".This").eq(0).val();
        alert(r);
    });
});

});
</script>

</head>


<body>

<div class="myRow">
    <input type="text" class="notThis" value="wrong!"/>
    <input type="text" class="This" value="first one!"/>
    <input type="text" class="This" value="almost!"/>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="myRow">
    <input type="text" class="notThis" value="wrong!"/>
    <input type="text" class="This" value="second one"/>
    <input type="text" class="This" value="almost!"/>
</div>


<button id="btn">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $(".myRow").each(function(){
        var r = $(".This:first", this).val();
        alert(r);
    });
});
```

Comment: According to various jsPerf tests, for example: http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-2 find is faster than context.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.This:eq(0)','.myRow').css('background-color','#F00');

$('.myRow').find('.This:eq(0)').css('border-color','#F00');

$('.This:first','.myRow').css('color','#0F0');

$('.myRow').find('.This:first').css('font-weight','bold');
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kCDy4/1/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $(".myRow").each(function(){
        var r = $(".This", this).eq(0).val();
        alert(r);
    });
});
```

To get both in a selector, you could always do:

```
var elems = $('.This:eq(0)', '.myRow');
```

Then you could do this to get an array of the values:

```
var values = $.map($('.This:eq(0)', '.myRow'), function(el) {return el.value});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qkPZm/2/)

Comment: IMO, the context argument is one of  jQuery's less intuitive features. Using `.find()` provides much clearer code.

Comment: IMO, context is great once you get used to it!

Comment: That's what I mean. An intuitive API doesn't require getting used to.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qkPZm/1/)

```
var r = $(this).find(".This").eq(0).val();
```

You need to look for `.This` relative to the current element, otherwise it will always find the first instance.

Side note: as an alternative to `.eq(0)` you can use `.first()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of JavaScript objects by using jQuery's factory method to search for a certain property. Example:

```
var search = $('input[class="This"]');
```

You can access the first one found by simply using:

```
search[0];
```

Essentially (and this is not the most optimized way of doing it), you can do this:

```
var rows = $('.myRow');
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var first;
    var row = $(rows[i]);
    var children = row.find('input[class="This"]');
    // You can also do row.find('input.This');

    if(children.length > 0) {
        first = children[0];

        // Do something with it
    }
}
```

Like I said, not the most optimal way, but each time you use the factory method, you're getting an array of objects and you can loop through them.

You can search through HTML properties like the above.

Examples:

```
$('input[type="button"]')
$('input[name="firstName"]')
$('a[href="www.google.com"]')
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $(".myRow input:nth-child(1)").each(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```